# Is there a way to append new xml data to already existing xml in an xml file without using XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Generally, I am writing log messages to an xml file. I use `Linq`'s `XDocument`.

I usually have unresponsive UI when the xml log becomes large thus I'm looking for an alternative to achieving the same result.

Below is an excerpt of how I logged to an xml file using `Linq`.

```
// Create the xml file if it does not exist
if (!File.Exists(_filePath))
{
    _xmlDocument = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("Logs"));

    _xmlDocument.Save(_filePath);
}

// Load the xml file
_xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(_filePath);

// Add new log to the logs
_xmlDocument?.Element("Logs")?
    .AddFirst(new XElement($"{logLevel.ToString()}",
              new XAttribute("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("g")),
              new XAttribute("Filepath", $"{values?[1]}"),
                  new XElement("Exception", new XAttribute("EventId", eventId), exception.Source),
                               new XElement("Message",
                               new XAttribute("Origin", $"{values?[0]}"),
                               new XAttribute("LineNumber", $"{values?[2]}"),
                               $"{values?[3]}")
                               )
              );

            // Save the document
            _xmlDocument.Save(_filePath);
```

Comment: Two things: 1) you are using .AddFirst which inserts entries on top meaning many entries have to be moved over time - .AppendChild would perform better. 2) avoid using ?. as you already ensured the document being available.

Comment: I'm looking to have new logs stay at the top always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique is to maintain the log file like this

```
<log-entry.../>
<log-entry.../>
<log-entry.../>
```

without an enclosing wrapper element. This means you can append to it using normal file append methods. Then when you want to read it as XML, reference it as an external entity from another file:

```
<!DOCTYPE log [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "logdata.xml">
]>
<log>&e;</log>
```

You still incur the full cost of parsing when you read the file, but you can now append to it directly and cheaply.

Of course the drawback is that security people these days are paranoid about external entities.

Comment: could you point me to any reference material that could help with implementing the technique you suggested?

Comment: A good book on XML, like Bob du Charme's, tells you everything you need to know about entities. Personally I use XML entities very little, but there's just occasionally a problem like this where they're very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Xml file as if it were a datatable, insert a record and then write the file again.
For example:

```
        DataSet oDataset = new DataSet();
        oDataset.ReadXml(yourfile);
        DataTable dt = oDataset.Tables["yourtable"];
        //Insert a record
        oDataset.WriteXml(yourfile);
```

Comment: Are there any trade-offs with this method that should be of concern?

Comment: I have used it for many years to manage configuration files, what were once .ini files, and have never had a problem.